# Lab expected, got String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, foreign-keys, associations

I heve case model. Case model have 3 fiels for id of lab model.
in Case model

```
belongs_to :lab1, foreign_key: 'lab1', class_name: 'Lab', inverse_of: :lab1, conditions: {step1: true}
belongs_to :lab2, foreign_key: 'lab2', class_name: 'Lab', inverse_of: :lab2, conditions: {step2: true}
belongs_to :lab3, foreign_key: 'lab3', class_name: 'Lab', inverse_of: :lab3, conditions: {step3: true}
```

in Lab model

```
has_many :lab1, foreign_key: 'lab1', class_name: 'Case', inverse_of: :lab1
has_many :lab2, foreign_key: 'lab2', class_name: 'Case', inverse_of: :lab2
has_many :lab3, foreign_key: 'lab3', class_name: 'Case', inverse_of: :lab3
```

And also form in case veiw

```
 .lab_group
   = f.association :lab1, label: false, input_html: {'data-placeholder'=> t('step.one')}
   = f.input :lab1_delivered, label: t('case.done')
 .lab_group
   = f.association :lab2, label: false, input_html: {'data-placeholder'=> t('step.two')}
   = f.input :lab2_delivered, label: t('case.done')
.lab_group
   = f.association :lab3, label: false, input_html: {'data-placeholder'=> t('step.three')}
   = f.input :lab3_delivered, label: t('case.done')
```

But when I try save it, I have a mistake

```
Lab(#70207759169540) expected, got String(#70207716712320)
```

and request params

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"G0BWY6V6tkxRt81I0ZOxKXs8RD/7cdfbZfhVfRTmboo=",
 "case"=>{"number"=>"123",
 "doctor_id"=>"1",
 "lab1"=>"1",
 "lab1_delivered"=>"0",
 "lab2"=>"2",
 "lab2_delivered"=>"0",
 "lab3"=>"2",
 "lab3_delivered"=>"0",
 "delivered"=>"0",
 "patient"=>"",
 "comment"=>"for example"},
 "commit"=>"Save"}
```

and screens

[image]

[image]
How I can fix it?

Comment: You should show the code that the error is referring to: **your `create` action**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
I had lab1, lab2, lab3 colums in my cases table. But foreign_key don't seen it. I changes name for lab1, lab2 and lab3 like lab1_id, lab2_id and lab3_id.
I remove foreign_key from associations.
Let's see.
in case model

```
belongs_to :lab1, class_name: 'Lab', inverse_of: :lab1, conditions: {step1: true}
belongs_to :lab2, class_name: 'Lab', inverse_of: :lab2, conditions: {step2: true}
belongs_to :lab3, class_name: 'Lab', inverse_of: :lab3, conditions: {step3: true}
```

in lab model

```
has_many :lab1, class_name: 'Case', inverse_of: :lab1
has_many :lab2, class_name: 'Case', inverse_of: :lab2
has_many :lab3, class_name: 'Case', inverse_of: :lab3
```

and in form

```
.lab_group
  = f.association :lab1, label: false, input_html: {'data-placeholder'=> t('step.one')}
  = f.input :lab1_delivered, label: t('case.done')
.lab_group
  = f.association :lab2, label: false, input_html: {'data-placeholder'=> t('step.two')}
  = f.input :lab2_delivered, label: t('case.done')
.lab_group
  = f.association :lab3, label: false, input_html: {'data-placeholder'=> t('step.three')}
  = f.input :lab3_delivered, label: t('case.done')
```

foreign_key not working :( Is it bug? May be.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using here names lab1, lab2, lab3 instead of lab1_id, lab2_id, lab3_id for foreign_keys names.

Comment: No, I had lab1 column in cases table. I guessed how I can fix it. I will write it now.